# Relacionar matriz de String com um vetor de Float em C

Tags: c, string, matriz, float

Preciso que o programa receba 20 nomes digitados pelo usuário, armazene em uma Matriz Char, e logo após receba os 20 salário dos usuários e armazene em um vetor Float. Consegui fazer até a parte em que o usuário deve utilizar o programa até requisitar a exibição de um Índice inválido (0 a 19 são os válidos); pois a matriz Char não aceita exibir os dados através do Index, ao menos não consegui de forma alguma exibir assim.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
   float sal[20];
   char nom[21][16];
   int index, n, s;
   //recebe os nomes
   for(n = 0; n < 21; n++){
           printf("Insira o nome do funcionario [%d] \n", n);
           gets(nom[n]);
   }
   //exibe os nomes
   for(n = 0; n < 21; n++){
           printf("%s", nom[n]);
       printf("\n");   
   }
   //recebe os salários
   for(s = 0; s < 20; s++){
       printf("Insira o salario do funcionario [%d] \n", s);
       scanf("%f", &sal[s]);
   }

   //exibe o nome e salário de acordo ao índice digitado pelo usuário
       while(index < 20)
   {
       printf("Indice escolhido: Funcionario %s %s ", nom[index][index]);
       printf("Salario %f ", sal[index]);
       printf("\n");
       printf("Qual o indice do Vetor que deseja consultar? \n");
       scanf("%d", &index);    
   }
   
   return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: Resolvido, a solução era bem simples na verdade: dentro do laço ```WHILE```  ao invés de usar ```printf``` para exibir os ```nom[index]```, era só usar o comando ```puts(nom[index]``` que exibe sem problemas.